# How can I format my active hard drive to NTFS?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to install Windows 7 with a 4GB flash drive, but my error that comes up is that my hard drive I'm trying to install on is in ext4. I need to format it to read NTFS. I can't seem to find any topics on how to format an active hard drive. I found a topic that explains how to move Ubuntu to a new drive, but it's a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Do you need to keep your ubuntu partition or just want to format the drive so it is readable by the Windows installer?

Answer (score 2):

So, I assume you are trying to format with ubuntu, and not wanting to keep ubuntu, so the best thing to do is to boot up to a live cd of ubuntu(most likely the disk you used to install ubuntu, if not [Ubuntu download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)) and use gparted off the live cd, [using gparted video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkXATVq75IQ), because you can't format the active partition while using it. Just keep in mind that formating the partition will get rid of ubuntu and all your data