# How can I format a hard drive in Ubuntu to use it as storage?

Tags: 12.10, hard-drive, format

I have an extra internal hard drive that I just want to use for storage. I want it to work with Windows (7) and Ubuntu. How could I just format it to have no operating system and just be used as storage while I'm on Ubuntu? Is their an application that can do this automatically? What do I format it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GParted software is the best option. To install Gparted goto Ubuntu Software center and search for gparted. And format for "**NTFS format**" following this video "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LApK79kc4jE" or this link "[How can I format my active hard drive to NTFS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119370/how-can-i-format-my-active-hard-drive-to-ntfs)".